# how to access helm charts folder

Tags: elasticsearch, charts, kubernetes-helm

I installed `Elasticsearch` using helm chart, I want to enable security on it. I did what's mentioned on the documentation but I have a problem accessing the folder `examples` to run the make file to enable security features.
 How can I access that file or where can I find it, and which command should I use so I could get to that location?